# containsObject NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Lets say I `alloc init` an object and this object contains the exact same data as an object in an array, the only difference would be the location in memory.

If I called `[myArray containsObject:identicalObject];` would it find the 'duplicate' object? Or does it only return true if the object is the exact same object in memory? If the objects match, like a `.equals` in java will that return true?

Answer (score 3):

`containsObject` [uses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject%3a) `isEqual:`. So, you should [override](http://nshipster.com/equality/) `isEqual:` and `hash` methods.